# I will head out to the campus when/if she is writing the essay - continuous tense in the future?

Tags: conjunctions, conditionals

**Example 1**

> I will head out to the campus when she is writing the essay.

**Example 2**

> I will head out to the campus if she is writing the essay.

Can we use progressive tense in an **if** or **when** clause?

**Example 3**

> I will head out when she is going to go to bed.

**Example 4**

> I will head out if she is going to go to bed.

Can we use "be going to" in an **if** or **when** clause?

---

Does the principle apply to other conjunction words, such as "in case" and "unless," and "as soon as"?

Comment: There's nothing unusual about *I'll head out **if / when** she's **going to go to bed***. Why do you think there might be a problem? Unless we know that, I don't see what anyone can usefully tell you here.

Comment: It seems more natural to say "I will [do something] **while** she is writing the essay" or "when she starts writing the essay" (I can do my own thing then because she won't need me/won't be available for me to talk to.)